How does FlatList rendering items with same names work?
Instead of saving views position its just delete them, or i dont know what it is doing to views and other elements,
i will show pictures it is easier to explain.
[![What i want 1][https://i.sstatic.net/gYoblXvI.png]

But instead i am fighting with this problems:


This is
part of first jsx file return value that is allowing me to make flatlist
      <FlatList
        data={uprosceno}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <VideoKarta
                video={item.naziv}
                kreator={item.korisnici.ime}
                urlPSlike={item.korisnici.avatar}
                tambnejl={item.tambnejl}
              ></VideoKarta>
            </View>
          );
        }}

This is second jsx file that uses  functional component
and also part of return value
 const [pritisnutKlip, pritisniKlip] = useState(false);



<View className="w-full flex-1" resizeMode="contain">
       {pustiKlip ? (
         <Text
           style={{ fontFamily: "PoppinsRegular", position: "absolute" }}
           className="text-lg text-gray-300"
         >
           Клип се пушта ...
         </Text>
       ) : (
         <View className="w-full h-full items-center flex-1 justify-center">
           <Text></Text>
           <TouchableOpacity
             onPress={() => {
               kreirajPKlipa(true);
               pritisnutKlip ? pritisniKlip(false) : pritisniKlip(true);
             }}
             className={`w-full border-2 ${
               pritisnutKlip ? "border-gray-500" : "border-cyan-300"
             } rounded-xl`}
             activeOpacity={0.7}
           >
             <Image
               className="w-full h-[240px] rounded-xl"
               source={{ uri: tambnejl }}
             ></Image>
           </TouchableOpacity>

           <Image
             source={slicice.play}
             className="w-16 h-16"
             style={{ position: "absolute" }}
           ></Image>
         </View>
       )}

       <Text></Text>
       <Text></Text>````


Also i noticed that if i set background color of this view it recognizes that view has some space between image loaded and view
[![Image](https://i.sstatic.net/wBQrlXY8.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/wBQrlXY8.png)

``<View className="w-full h-full items-center flex-1 justify-center bg-white">
   <Text></Text>
     <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
       kreirajPKlipa(true);
...``


 [1]: 



make sure the parent of the flatlist have some space
you can test that by hardcoding some values for the flastlist like ```jsx
<FlatList
style={{
minHeight:400
}}
/>



Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
